# how to load the data to combo box using xml file .and not duplicate times in box only single time

Tags: c#

```
 private void cmbBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             try
            {
                XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
                xdoc = XDocument.Load("//txt.xml");
                List<XElement> listXele = new List<XElement>();


                List<userClass> clsList = new List<userClass>();
                foreach (var val in listXele)
                {
                    userClass obj = new userClass();
                    obj.City = val.Element("City").Value;
                  // i want city node in cmbo box only for once


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: <Users>
  <User>
    <UserName>Aaisha</UserName>
    <UserPassword>QWRtaW4xMjM0</UserPassword>
 <Account>savings</Account>
 <City>chennai</City> 
  </User>
  <User>
    <UserName>support</UserName>
    <UserPassword>U3RvcmUwOTg3</UserPassword>
 <Account>savings</Account>
 <City>Madurai</City>
  </User>
  <User>
    <UserName>amazon service</UserName>
    <UserPassword>Rm9vZDEyMzQ=</UserPassword>
  <Account>savings</Account>
 <City>Pandy</City>
    
  </User>

Comment: if we select chennai .then it will be updated in datagrid and it will show the all users from chennai like.please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the form's Load event to populate the combo box, in which case you can do something like this:

```
  private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
            xdoc = XDocument.Load("//txt.xml");
            List<XElement> listXele = new List<XElement>();


            List<userClass> clsList = new List<userClass>();
            foreach (var val in listXele)
            {
                userClass obj = new userClass();
                obj.City = val.Element("City").Value;

                // Check if the combo box doesn't already have the city name
                // assuming you are populating the combo box with strings only

                // Check for null/empty string 
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.City))
                {
                     if(!cmbBox.Items.Contains(obj.City))
                         cmbBox.Items.Add(obj.City);
                }


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ideally, though, you would have a separate XML file (or preferably a database table) that contains the list of "available" cities to select, and you would load *only* that list to the combo box instead of looping through a potentially large XML file record-by-record to load a small list of cities.

Comment: some build errors are coming .it doesnt reading xml file .am new to wpf

Comment: please tell me the  above solution #alex

Comment: Maybe try to change `myForm_Load` back to `cmbBox_Load`, and let me know if that fixes the problem.  Also, you will obviously need to change `userClass` back to the name of your object class.  Additionally, you will need to change  this code:

             `if(!cmbBox.Items.Contains(obj.City))
                         cmbBox.Items.Add(obj.City);`

to use the name of your actual ComboBox control.

Comment: thank you alex it works fine until. another question is i need to show  the users from xml based on the combobox selection  city .how to bind datagrid and combobox

Comment: Please accept my answer so I receive reputation points for it, and I will try to assist with the second question as well.